# Can't create multiple instances of the same image docker docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few docker-compose files to test different environments, for example testing vs development vs production.

My main issue is using the postgres image, creating different databases for each environment. Here is an example of two different environments' docker-compose.yml files:

docker-compose.first.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:

    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=first
      - POSTGRES_DB=first
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

docker-compose.second.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:

    image: "postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=second
      - POSTGRES_DB=second
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

If I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.first.yml up`, I want it to build with the previous volumes of the first docker-compose file.

If I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.second.yml up`, I want it to use the volumes of the **second** docker-compose file.

Right now, the behavior is that each of these files will use the same volumes, so unless I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.first.yml -v down` before using the second one, there won't be any change, and I'll lose the volumes of the first one! How can I keep these separate?

Note: These files are in the same directory, does that make a difference?

Comment: Why don't you have a single docker-compose file, omit the values for any environment variables,and put these values in different ".env" files for each configuration ?

See the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here after doing research about same-directory docker-compose files is that the names determine if a container will be freshly created or recreated, determining the volumes it uses.

Docker-compose by default uses the directory name as the "compose project name" so the name could be mytestproject_db_1 because it goes project-name_container-name_numerator. Since the compose files are in the same directory, they have the same name since none of the factors change.

To fix this, you manually change the "compose project name" using the -p option, so I could do `docker-compose up -p test-myapp` or `docker-compose up -p prod-myapp` to make sure the compose files won't be linked.

More info: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2120